# Adding border to table cell issue

Tags: html, css

I am having a weird issue regarding to my table. I want to add `border` to my `rows` so the user can tell
the difference between each `rows`..

My html

```
<table>
  <tr class='rows'>
    <td class='test'> test1</td>
    <td class='test'> test2</td>
    <td class='test'> test3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='rows'>
    <td class='test'> test8</td>
    <td class='test'> test9</td>
    <td class='test'> test7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='rows'>
    <td class='test'> test4</td>
    <td class='test'> test5</td>
    <td class='test'> test6</td>
  </tr>

   more...
</table>
```

my table css

```
table{
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;
}

.rows{
  border: solid 5px red;  //this border properties doesn't work.
  background-color:grey;  //this would change the background colors
}
```

I couldn't figure out what went wrong in my codes. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you merely just have the border property children in the wrong order. I think it will work if you change it to 5px solid red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borders can't be applied to table-rows unless you change the `display` property. The recommended solution is to set borders on table-cells:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table td {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

If you need space between table-cells you can use `padding`.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the

```
display:table;
```

in your css..

[Look at this jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/)